# How do I populate a dropdown in the EditItemTemplate of a Grdivew?

Tags: gridview

I have 3 drop downs total. 1 in the Footer for new records. One in the Empty Template, also for new records. Both get popualted in the RowDataBound method of the gridview.

```
Protected Sub gvCaseInfo_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvICaseInfo.RowDataBound

Dim ddl As New DropDownList
Dim luMgt As New LookupMgt

Select Case e.Row.RowType
    Case DataControlRowType.EmptyDataRow
        ddl = CType(e.Row.Controls(0).FindControl("ddlEmptyLocationType"), DropDownList)
    Case DataControlRowType.Footer
        ddl = CType(e.Row.Controls(0).FindControl("ddlFooterLocationType"), DropDownList)
End Select

ddl.DataSource = luMgt.GetLookUpItemList(Of LocationType)()
ddl.DataBind()
```

End Sub

But I can't figure out where to hwo to popualte the dropdown that is in the EditItemTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the row's state and see if it is in edit mode. If it is then you can grab your dropdownlist with FindControl() (still in the RowDataBound function).

```
if((e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit) ||  (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit | DataControlRowState.Alternate))
{
       //Get dropdown
       //Do stuff
}
```

This is in C#, though. Sorry!